# I want to get all contacts in windows phone 7 in a list

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, contacts

I want to get a list of all contacts in my windows phone OS to edit in all contacts and save it ?

I know that Microsoft.Phone.Tasks; get contacts application can I get this contacts and edit it without show it from this class ?

I want it in windows phone 7 not 7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contacts are readonly in Mango and are not available at all before Mango. Here how you can read them in Mango: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286414%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

I think with the [choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707923%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) from Microsoft.Phone.Tasks you can only add new contacts (with user's consent). You can't delete or modify existing contacts.

Comment: You can use the SaveContactTask to add new contacts

Comment: `SaveContactTask` is the name of one of the chooserd I mentioned, there are more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707923(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do lot of those stuff within windows live.com site.

I wanted to get all contacts from my Mango, but i couldn't get it within the phone.
So, what I did was,

I synced all my contacts to SkyDrive on windows live, and exported it from live.com web site.

[image]

you can export contacts to a excel sheet and do what ever you want from it.